# Watch for changes on all sass files and save them in one css file

Tags: css, sass

In my package.json I have the following script:

```
"watch:sass": "node-sass -w sass/main.scss style/style.css "
```

It waits for changes in main.scss file and then changes style.css respectively. My main.scss file is basically a collection, which imports a bunch of other scss files.

```
@import "abstracts/variables"; //abstracts/_variables.scss
@import "abstracts/mixins"; // abstracts/_mixins.scss
@import "base/base";  //base/_base.scss
@import "base/typography"; //base/_typography.scss
```

The problem is that when I'm in other scss file, for example I edit _base.scss, when I change it and save - my style.css doesn't update itself automatically. Only when I go back to main.scss and save it, only then style.css gets refreshed.

How can I make changes in any of my sass files so that  style.css will be updated too?

Comment: "watch:sass": "node-sass -w sass/*.scss style/style.css "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a Wildcard `*`:

```
"watch:sass": "node-sass -w sass/*.scss style/style.css"
```

But make sure all your SCSS files are inside `sass` folder.

Comment: @AshleyRedmanBSc Ahh! Didn't see that... `:(` Anyway, if this answer doesn't work for the OP, I'll be happy to delete it. Hey, you too from Leicester? `:)`

Comment: No problem and I am yeah!

Comment: Can I ask you about asterisk symbol? Why exactly can we use it? Is it a part of npm or it's kind of a bash thing?!

Comment: @MichaelKlim It's in any directory selection, it selects all the files with `.scss` extensions. For example, in Windows, Linux or macOS, when you search for all the PDFs, you would be giving a search term of `*.pdf`. It's something like that. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Thanks for help! Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
"scss": "node-sass --watch sass/main.scss:css/style.css"
```

this worked for me.